# EACCES error when sending datagram on Windows

Tags: windows, node.js, sockets, udp

My program throw an EACCES error when execute send() method of dgram.udp4 socket, but only does it on Windows.

The code:

```
var dgram       = require('dgram');

var monsocket   = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

monsocket.on("listening", function () {     comBroadcastCallUp(); });

var comBroadcastCallUp = function() {
    var message = new Buffer(JSON.stringify({ 
        protocol: "psdp", 
        command: "call-up" 
    }));

    monsocket.setBroadcast(true);
    monsocket.send(message, 0, message.length, 32681, '255.255.255.255', function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err)
            else console.log("<PcStatus:PSDP> Message sent: " + message + os.EOL + "Message length: " + message.length);
    });
    monsocket.setBroadcast(false);
}

monsocket.bind(32681);
```

Same code, terminal output on Windows:

```
{ [Error: send EACCES] code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall: 'send' }
```

Terminal output on Linux:

```
<PcStatus:PSDP> Message sent: {"protocol":"psdp","command":"call-up"}
Message length: 39
```

I check the firewall, if other program kept the port busy, nothing...

Comment: Did you also try running node as administrator on Windows to see if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadcasting to `255.255.255.255` is not supported anymore as of Windows 7 I believe. You will need to limit the send to a particular subnet instead.

Also keep in mind that not all routers will route packets destined for `255.255.255.255`.